# Passing String to Spring Web Flow with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf, spring-webflow

I've basic problem with passing `String` from `<input>` in my view to webflow

```
<view-state id="tagsSubflow" view="places/add-flow/tags">
    <var name="newTag" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <on-entry>
        <set name="viewScope.newTag" value="new java.lang.String()"/>
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="next" to="save"/>
    <on-exit>
        <evaluate expression="place.addTag(newTag)"/>
    </on-exit>
</view-state>
```

My example `<input>` Thymeleaf

```
<input type="text" th:field="${newTag}"/>
```

I'm getting exception
`The expression string to parse is required and must not be empty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my problem  just used converter like this

I have created my own converter like this

```
public class TagsUtils implements Converter {

public static Set<Tag> getTagsFromString(String tags) {
    Set<Tag> tagSet = new HashSet<>();
    String[] splittedTags = tags.split(",");
    for (String stringTag : splittedTags) {
        stringTag = stringTag.trim();
        Tag tag = new Tag(stringTag);
        tagSet.add(tag);
    }
    return tagSet;
}

@Override
public Class<?> getSourceClass() {
    return String.class;
}

@Override
public Class<?> getTargetClass() {
    return Set.class;
}

@Override
public Object convertSourceToTargetClass(Object o, Class<?> aClass) throws Exception {
    return getTagsFromString((String) o);
}
}
```

I added to the view state a binder

```
    <binder>
        <binding property="tags" converter="tagConverter"/>
    </binder>
```

And create configuration

```
@Service("MyConversionService")
public class ApplicationConversionService extends DefaultConversionService {

public ApplicationConversionService() {
    addDefaultConverters();
    addDefaultAliases();
    addConverter("tagConverter", new TagsUtils());
}
}
```

and the last step was add this custom conversion service to webflow config, like this

```
<flow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices"
                            conversion-service="MyConversionService"
                            view-factory-creator="mvcViewFactoryCreator"
                            development="true"/>
```

my html input looks just like this `<input class="form-group" type="text" th:field="${place.tags}" />`